general relativity on cadabra2 gives me unexpected outputs
I've been trying to find the curvature of the Robertson-Walker metric on cadabra. But the problem arises as the christoffel symbol calculated by the software turns out to be zeo. can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?
{t, x, y, z}::Coordinate.
{\lambda}::Depends(t);
f_{a b}::Metric.
f^{a b}::InverseMetric.
\delta_{a}^{b}::KroneckerDelta.
\nabla{#}::Derivative.
\partial{#}::PartialDerivative. 

#flrw mwtric
ss := { f_{t t} = - 1,
f_{x x} = \lambda^2,
f_{y y} = \lambda^2,
f_{z z} = \lambda^2};

ssinv := { f^{t t} = - 1,
f^{x x} = \lambda^(-2),
f^{y y} = \lambda^(-2),
f^{z z} = \lambda^(-2)};

#defining rules (covariant derivative and christoffel symbols)
nabla := \nabla_{c}{f_{a b}} -> \partial_{c}{f_{a b}} - f_{a d} \Gamma^{d}_{b c}- f_{d b} \Gamma^{d}_{a c};
Gamma := \Gamma^{a}_{b c} -> (1/2) f^{a d} ( \partial_{b}{f_{d c}} + \partial_{c}{f_{b d}} - \partial_{d}{f_{b c}} );

p=evaluate (Gamma, ss, rhsonly=True); 

